# I want to click a picture of document and crop it (like cam scanner), this to be done when user clicks on my sliverList. I am new to flutter

Tags: flutter, listview, dart, camera

Remember it is 3rd page where i want my onPressed to open camera and crop image.
Tell me code for both android and Ios.

```
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
  import 'package:telemed/pages/size_config.dart';
  import 'strings.dart';
  import 'package:camera/camera.dart';

  class User extends StatefulWidget {
 
 List<CameraDescription> cameras;
 Future<void> main() async {
 runApp(); // what to write here instead of all this code.it is my 3rd page of flutter  
 WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
 final cameras = await availableCameras();

 @override
 _PatientState createState() => _UserState();
}

class _UserState extends State<User> {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Scaffold(
  body: CustomScrollView(
      slivers: <Widget>[
        Container(
          child: SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((context, index) {
              return Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                color: Colors.white,
                child: Text('Patient ${index}'),
                height: 120,
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(1),
              );
            }, childCount: 20),
          ),
        )
      ],
    ));
  } // please ignore any extra curly braces...
 }
```

my main aim is that user touches my sliverListview (like whatsapp but opens camera to crop a document clicked via camera instead of chat).

Answer (score 0):

Please, read the relevant Flutter documentation about Widgets, then read the `camera` package documentation.

Configure your project to support camera and photo library access as per the documentation.

Then you can wrap your `Container` in an `InkWell` widget and use its `onTap` callback to then invoke the `initialize` method on your `CameraController`.

The `camera` package is built with support for both Android and iOS, so the Flutter code you write will work on both platforms.

You can use either `image_crop` or `flutter_native_image` packages to crop resulting image.

I hope you don't expect me (or anyone else) to write the whole app for you.